# how to get full length DDL for all the indices on tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I went through related questions posted earlier on the site , but none of them gives out the complete DDL for postgresql.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have around 800 tables and I've moved them to new database using one etl tool  , now I've tables and data on new database but they are not indexed so I want to copy the DDL from old to new one,I can do it one by one but I was trying to find out if I can do it in one go...

Comment: So what have you tried, and what were the problems you got?

Comment: I could just get the  names of all indexes but not their ddl...

Comment: found this query online but it gives  just the description of the constraints :SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname
    ,c.relname AS tablename 
    ,200000000 || CAST(con.oid AS INT) AS seq 
    ,'\t,' || pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid) AS ddl 
  FROM pg_constraint AS con 
   INNER JOIN pg_class AS c ON c.relnamespace = con.connamespace AND c.oid = con.conrelid 
   INNER JOIN pg_namespace AS n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
   WHERE c.relkind = 'r' AND pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid) NOT LIKE 'FOREIGN KEY%' 
 ORDER BY seq

Comment: Don't post code or additional information as comments. **[edit]** your question and use [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the SQL for all indexes in your database:

```
select pg_get_indexdef(format('%I.%I', schemaname, indexname)::regclass)
from pg_indexes
where schemaname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
and schemaname not like 'pg_temp%';
```